# Twisted subchild

Tags: python, twisted

I am trying to create a nested resource (subchild) where the main child does not have anything, just a dummy page if anything.  So for instance I am trying to make the following resources.

```
/saml/login
/saml/logout
/saml/acs
/saml/sls
```

But I dont have or really need a /saml resource, just need the children.

I am not sure how to add a single subchild, let alone a subchild without a parent,  I can create a dummy /saml resource if needed but still need the nested pages.

Here is what I have so far.

```
class Hello(Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def getChild(self, name, request):
        if name == '':
            return self
        return Resource.getChild(self, name, request)

    def render_GET(self, request):
        return b"Hello, world! I am located at"

class SamlManager(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
        self.login_callback = None

    def init_app(self, root):
        root.saml_manager = self  # expose for login_from_acs
        root.putChild(b'saml', Hello())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NoResource` for a resource that you want to return a 404 response when requested:

```
from twisted.web.resource import Resource, NoResource

saml = NoResource()
saml.putChild(b"login", ...)
saml.putChild(b"logout", ...)
...

root = Resource()
root.putChild(b"saml", saml)
```